# How to create Linux and MacOS executables using PyInstaller on Windows?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable

I used Pyinstaller to make a standalone portable application for windows from python code, and it works normally.

I understand that to create an executable for a certain OS it must be done on that specific OS.

Is there a way to create executables for other platforms directly from windows without running a virtual machine.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to accept an answer (tick the check-mark next to an answer) if it answers your question. In this way your question stops from showing up as _unanswered_. Also up-vote good answers. – As you're starting out here, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and have a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Since pyinstaller is not a cross-compiler (which means with pyinstaller you cannot create an executable for any other system than the  one you are on), you will have to look for other tools.

On the official github FAQ, they recommend using [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) for this specific purpose.

Link to [FAQ](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/FAQ).

Since you don't want to look for other systems to compile your code on, this seems to be the only option.

Answer (score 1):

if you have docker-expertise, you could try to get the docker-containers in the following link to do the job for you (creating the executable for windows/linux by setting up a docker-container for each target-system) and starting up the Docker-Containers for Building the Executables from within your Windows-OS. I have not tryed it out though, but the Readme of the project sounds promising.

https://github.com/cdrx/docker-pyinstaller

If the project does what it says, you would only need to execute the following two commands in your project-folder to create the executables for Windows and Linux, when you have gotten everything setted up:

`docker run -v "$(pwd):/src/" cdrx/pyinstaller-windows`

`docker run -v "$(pwd):/src/" cdrx/pyinstaller-linux`

Answer (score 0):

In order to make executable files for Mac and Linux, you need to build it on the same systems
For example, in order to make your Linux work, you need to collect the rpm package

Answer (score 0):

No, pyinstaller [isn't a cross-compiler](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/FAQ#features), so just use VM.